# using pyspark I want to max sum the count for hour 0 is there any possibility to do it

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

v = Vehicle_counter_DF.select("hour","classname").filter(vehicle_counter_DF.cosit.isin(li)).groupBy("classname", "hour").count().orderBy("hour")
v.show(truncate=False)

```
+---------+----+-----+
|classname|hour|count|
+---------+----+-----+
|LGV      |0   |272  |
|HGV_ART  |0   |309  |
|MBIKE    |0   |7    |
|BUS      |0   |123  |
|CAR      |0   |2167 |
|HGV_RIG  |0   |33   |
|CARAVAN  |0   |3    |
|HGV_ART  |1   |208  |
|LGV      |1   |208  |
|HGV_RIG  |1   |55   |
|MBIKE    |1   |6    |
|BUS      |1   |42   |
|CAR      |1   |1381 |
|CARAVAN  |1   |7    |
|HGV_ART  |2   |145  |
|CARAVAN  |2   |3    |
|MBIKE    |2   |6    |
|HGV_RIG  |2   |47   |
|CAR      |2   |1028 |
|LGV      |2   |181  |
+---------+----+-----+
```

i want the o/p like

```
+---------+----+-----+
|classname|hour|count|
+---------+----+-----+
|LGV      |0   |272  |
|HGV_ART  |0   |309  |
|MBIKE    |0   |7    |
|BUS      |0   |123  |
|CAR      |0   |2167 |
|HGV_RIG  |0   |33   |
|CARAVAN  |0   |3    |
```

Comment: You should describe your problem better. Does this `v = Vehicle_counter_DF.select("hour","classname").filter(vehicle_counter_DF.cosit.isin(li)).groupBy("classname", "hour").count().orderBy("hour") v.show(truncate=False)` doing anything with your question?

Answer (score 0):

Question not clear but it appear to me like you would like to filter rows with zeros?

```
df = df.filter(df.hour == 0)
df.display()
```